# How can I get the query result which includes IF ELSE when using pymssql on SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I am using `pymssql` in python application to connect to SQL Server database. I have a query statement defined as below:

```
DECLARE @type int
SELECT @type = type FROM myTable WHERE id = 1000

IF @type >= 700
    SELECT 1
ELSE
    SELECT 0
```

when I run the above sql in SQL Server, I can get output either `1` or `0` which depends on the `type` value of the row. But when I run the code in python it always returns `None`:

```
cursor.execute(sql)  # sql is the above select statement
cursor.fetchone()  # this line return None
```

What I am expecting is to get the value 1 or 0, how can I achieve it in `pymssql`?

Comment: I'm not sure you can run dynamic SQL like this outside of SQL Server, or maybe outside of a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code to this. `type` is a reserved keyword in sql server. Added `TOP 1` to make sure we will only get 1 result for `[type]`.

```
DECLARE @type int
SET @type = 0
SELECT TOP 1 @type = [type] FROM myTable WHERE id = 1000

IF @type >= 700
    SELECT 1
ELSE
    SELECT 0
```

Comment: It works and I can see the result. Could you explain a little more why adding `TOP 1` in the select statement?

Comment: Added `TOP 1` to make sure we will only get 1 result for `[type]`.

Comment: but if it doesn't return 1 result, I will get 0 as return value, right?

Comment: no, you need to add SET @type = 0 before your select

Comment: so the `if` statement will throw exception if the select returns more than 1 rows?